# Determining error between two surfaces given same discrete inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, error, fitting

Apologies if this isnt the best SE forum to ask on, but it seems relevant here.

I have, as an output of a machine learning algorithm, a surface in z, which has known increments along x and y. These points along x and y match exactly to a surface which I am comparing the output of my algorithm against in order to get a metric of fit, or error. I have been struggling to find an optimal way of calculating this, and can't find any good resources on different options that I have.

I have tried simple pointwise subtraction of the surfaces, which I take the absolute value and summation of, and I have tried squared versions of this, as well as calculating MSE, RMSE, and R2, but each of these encounters different problems. The best version I have tried so far is the simple subtraction squared, and the other version tend to give "flatter", more spread out surfaces. I suspect this may be because the values in z of my surfaces are much smaller than 1, on the order of 0.001. I have thus tried adding 1 and then calculating the different metrics, but this seemed to make the problem worse.

I was wondering if any of you knew of any better ways of fitting, or any good resources on different options and which of these work in different situations. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are using several standard loss functions. There is nothing wrong with any of them. You say you have "different problems" with each loss function, but it isn't clear what those problems are. Failure to minimize? Slowly converging best fits?Maybe you just don't like the graphics? If you rescale $z$, perhaps by setting $z \rightarrow (z-min(z))/(max(z)-min(z))$, then $min(z)=0$ and $max(z)=1$ and your visualization tools might give you a better picture to look at.

Comment: As I described in the second paragraph, my issues tend to optimize towards flatter or wider distributions. Sorry I did not mention, I believe that this is an effect of overemphasizing when there are outliers in the comparison surface. Because of this, it flattens out in order to be able to subtract from the outliers, but is a worse model overall. This has nothing to do whatsoever with my visualization. Thank you for the rescaling suggestion, I will try it, but I have doubts that a simple rescale will effect the shape of the optimization function, as it will affect each value equally.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion of linear rescaling should not affect your results, only your graphics. Perhaps you are suffering from outliers dominating your model. Are you looking for a way to identify outliers for removal? Or are you looking for a loss function that weights "central" points stronger than distant ones?

Comment: The latter would be great, yeah. Effectively, I would like to weight "central" points more strongly, but with some level of flexibility in the case that there are not outliers affecting the data to a great extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you are free to use any loss function you want to use for your regression. I'm not able to find a mathematically precise definition of a loss function, which seems surprising to me.   [Here is a paper from 2007](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228689578_Some_thoughts_about_the_design_of_loss_functions) that addresses the problem from a fairly lofty perspective. There is even a section called "Philosophical Aspects." You have been warned!

You are free to include a radial decay function in your loss, which might suit you. That is, you might use something like

$$
Radial~Decay~OLS~Loss(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m|{data},\alpha) \\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= \sum_{i=1}^N (\hat{z}(x_i,y_i|\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m)-z_i)^2 exp(-(r_i/r_{max})^{\alpha}),
$$

where the Euclidean distance $r=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$, $r_{max}$ is the distance to the most distant outlier and $(x_0,y_0)$ is some notion of the center of your data. Mean? Median? Your call. $\alpha$ is a shape parameter. When you establish a sense of what you like, you might commit to using that $\alpha$ in your problem space from now on. You should report your results are conditional on this loss function and the particular value of a $\alpha$ that you've chosen. (Perhaps you will even name $\alpha$ after yourself. ;) )

I did find a loss function called  [Huber Loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) which was designed to minimize the effect of outliers. It might also suit. But I would defer to @whuber for an explanation of that.

Comment: Perfect! This is very close to exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! As for alpha, I may just have to name it the Leopold number, haha.